# How to read estimote beacons with my pc?

Tags: javascript, beacon

I have Estimote Beacons, I am developing an app in Evothings Studio, the app works with my smartphone and my lap connected en the same net, I want to know if is possible convert my PC in a beacons reader, this way I will develop this app without my phone.

Comment: You need an NFC reader.

Answer (score 2):

The [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) Node.js module has some degree of support for discovering Bluetooth LE devices on Windows, albeit it's actually a bit tricky to set it up. You need a special driver, one of very few compatible BLE USB dongles, and go through some shenanigans to bypass the Windows Bluetooth stack and gain direct access to your Bluetooth adapter. Not for the faint hearted.

https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble#windows

https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-bluetooth-hci-socket#windows

If you manage to set this up, there's a dedicated Node.js module that builds on top of noble and provides an easy way to discover beacons specifically:

https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-bleacon

Answer (score -1):

Only windows 10 devices with onboard Bluetooth Low Energy are capable of scanning for Bluetooth LE beacons.  Older Windows operating systems to not support this.

The above speaks to the hardware support.  Unfortunately, as of November 2015, I'm currently unaware of any general purpose beacon scanning programs that run on Windows.  Unless there is a new one I haven't found, you may be out of luck.